# ¿Cómo acceder a los campos de una base de datos sin usar estamentos SQL?

Tags: c++, qt, mariadb

lo que quiero hacer es obtener los valores del campo "name" de la tabla "users" de la base de datos "ventanaderegistrodb" y mostrarlos por la consola, pero sin usar consultas SQL, es decir usando sólo métodos.

Resolver este sencillo problema me proporcionará todos los conocimientos para resolver mi problema real en una aplicación:

El código es el siguiente(que no me funciona):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QSqlField>



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :  QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mDataBase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    mDataBase.setHostName("localhost");
    mDataBase.setPort(3306);
    mDataBase.setUserName("root");
    mDataBase.setPassword("javier2001");
    mDataBase.setDatabaseName("ventanaderegistrodb");
    if (!mDataBase.open()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "DB Eroor", mDataBase.lastError().text());
        return;
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_loginButton_clicked() {
    QString userName = ui->userLineEdit->text();
    QString userPassword = ui->passwordLineEdit->text();

    mModel = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    mModel->setTable("users");
    mModel->select();

    QSqlRecord userTableRecord = mModel->record();
    QSqlField userNameField = userTableRecord.field(mModel->fieldIndex("name"));
    QStringList s = userNameField.value().toStringList();
    for (QStringList::iterator it = s.begin(); it < s.end(); it++) {
        qDebug() << *it;
    }
}
```

Gracias por colaborar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mecanismo utilizado por defecto por Qt es **SQL**. Qt, por tanto, no te va a proporcionar ninguna otra forma de interactuar con la base de datos.

Por otro lado, mariadb es una base de datos **SQL**, es decir, su interfaz usa, exclusivamente, SQL.

Dicho de otra forma: No existe ningún mecanismo en este escenario que te permita hacer uso de la citada base de datos sin usar, en algún momento, SQL.

Ahora bien, lo que puedes hacer es currarte una capa de acceso a datos que escriba el SQL por ti... pero ya te adelanto que no es un camino que se vaya a recorrer rápido ya que tiene bastante trabajo (y te lo digo por experiencia).

Otra cosa que puedes hacer, más rápida y viable, es crearte una capa de acceso a datos que aglutine todas las consultas SQL que puedas necesitar. Agrupar las consultas SQL suele ser una buena idea de cara a mantenimientos posteriores. Esta solución puede allanarte el camino de cara a, en el futuro, implementar una capa que escriba el SQL de forma automática.

Como ves todas las soluciones pasan por usar SQL... ahora te toca a ti decidir qué camino vas a seguir.

Comment: Ok, te agradezco tu ayuda, pero una ultima pregunta, ¿cómo va eso de la capa de acceso que escribe el SQL por ti? ¿Esa metodología tiene algún nombre en particular para poder documentarme?

Comment: @zuninool04 es simplemente un conjunto de clases con las que tu configuras la consulta... pero manejando clases en vez de sql... con eso se genera la sentencia sql final... yo en tu lugar no me plantearía aun esta situación... asienta conocimientos antes